# Panasonic and JTapi

Tags: java, jtapi

I try to create a application which monitoring the outgoing calls and other PBX controls of Panasonic PBX's with Java. The Panasonic only offers the Tapi Driver, but I cannot find any tutorial or example of. Can anyone know I good tutorial or some code example's to share?

Answer (score 0):

The best documentation is the main [docs](http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7169-jtapi-1.2-doc-oth-JSpec/), but for Panasonic specific stuff you'd have to dig yourself I think. Although Cisco and Avaya offer quite some examples and documentation, but can be specific to their version of JTApi.